# Changing object property through $set gives:" TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined "

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, set, typeerror

First of all, hello.

I'm relatively new to web development and Vue.js or Javascript. I'm trying to implement a system that enables users to upload and vote for pictures and videos. In general the whole system worked. But because i got all of my information from the server, the objects used to show the files + their stats wasn't reactive. I tried to change the way i change the properties of an object from "file['votes'] ) await data.data().votes" to "file.$set('votes', await data.data().votes)". However now i'm getting the TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined Error. I have no idea why this happens or what this error even means. After searching a lot on the internet i couldn't find anybody with the same problem. Something must be inheritly wrong with my approach.

If anybody can give me an explanation for what is happening or can give me a better way to handle my problem, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks in advance for anybody willing to try. Here is the Code section i changed:

```js
async viewVideo() {
  this.videoURLS = []
  this.videoFiles = []
  this.videoTitels = []
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  var videourl = []
  console.log("try")
  var listRef = storageRef.child('User-Videos/');
  var firstPage = await listRef.list({
    maxResults: 100
  });
  videourl = firstPage
  console.log(videourl)
  if (firstPage.nextPageToken) {
    var secondPage = await listRef.list({
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: firstPage.nextPageToken,
    });
    videourl = firstPage + secondPage

  }
  console.log(this.videoURLS)
  if (this.videoURLS.length == 0) {
    await videourl.items.map(async refImage => {

      var ii = refImage.getDownloadURL()
      this.videoURLS.push(ii)
    })

    try {
      await this.videoURLS.forEach(async file => {

        var fale2 = undefined
        await file.then(url => {
          fale2 = url.substring(url.indexOf("%") + 3)
          fale2 = fale2.substring(0, fale2.indexOf("?"))
        })
        await db.collection("Files").doc(fale2).get().then(async data => {
          file.$set('titel', await data.data().titel)
          file.$set('date', await data.data().date)
          if (file.$set('voted', await data.data().voted)) {
            file.$set('voted', [])
          }
          file.$set('votes', await data.data().votes)
          if (file.$set('votes', await data.data().votes)) {
            file.$set('votes', 0)
          }
          await this.videoFiles.push(file)
          this.uploadDate = data.data().date
          console.log(this.videoFiles)
          this.videoFiles.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.date - b.date;
          })
        })
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
},
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly, `file.$set('votes', await data.data().votes)` is the wrong syntax to use. It should be `this.$set(file, 'votes', data.data().votes)`. I am guessing the second `data` with `data()` returns an object with votes as a property.

Your use of await is not necessary here. `await db.collection("Files").doc(fale2).get().then(async data => {....`

You are already using a promise in the form of the `.then` block here. Async-await and the `then/catch` blocks are basically doing the same thing. It's one or the other.

Please check this fantastic [post](https://medium.com/jspoint/javascript-promises-and-async-await-as-fast-as-possible-d7c8c8ff0abc) that covers how to deal with asynchronous code in javascript. Learning about the asynchronous nature of javascript is highly essential right now.

There's a fair bit to pick on, and for now my focus is on removing things from your code that are either redundant or may not make it work. I am not focusing on the logic. With more information, I may make necessary edits for the logic.

I will leave comments in the code, where I feel they are necessary

```js
async viewVideo() {
  this.videoURLS = []
  this.videoFiles = []
  this.videoTitels = []
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  var videourl = '' // videourl should be initialised as a string 
  console.log("try")
  var listRef = storageRef.child('User-Videos/');
  var firstPage = listRef.list({  // the await here isn't necessary as this function isn't expected to return a promise(isn't asynchronous) to the best of my knowledge.
    maxResults: 100
  });
  videourl = firstPage
  console.log(videourl)
  if (firstPage.nextPageToken) {
    var secondPage = listRef.list({  // same as above
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: firstPage.nextPageToken,
    });
    videourl = firstPage + secondPage // videourl is a string here

  }
  console.log(this.videoURLS)
  if (this.videoURLS.length == 0) {
    videourl.items.map(async refImage => { //videourl is acting as an object here (something seems off here) - please explain what is happening here
// again await is not needed here as the map function does not return a promise

      var ii = refImage.getDownloadURL()
      this.videoURLS.push(ii)
    })

    try {
      this.videoURLS.forEach(file => { // await here is not necessary as the forEach method does not return a promise

      // The 'async' keyword is not necessary here. It is required to use the await keyword and due to the database call here, ordinarily it wouldn't be out of place, but you deal with that bit of asynchronous code using a `.then` block. It's `async-await` or `.then` and never both.

        var fale2 = undefined
        file.then(url => { // await is not necessary here as you use `.then`
        // Also, does `file` return a promise? That's the only thing I can infer from `file.then`. It looks odd.
          fale2 = url.substring(url.indexOf("%") + 3)
          fale2 = fale2.substring(0, fale2.indexOf("?"))
        })
         db.collection("Files").doc(fale2).get().then(data => { // await and async not necessary due to the same reasons outlined above
          this.$set(file, 'titel', data.data().titel) // correct syntax according to vue's documentation - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

          this.$set(file, 'date', data.data().date)
          if (this.$set(file, 'voted', data.data().voted)) { // I don't know what's going on here, I will just correct the syntax. I am not focused on the logic at this point
            this.$set(file, 'voted', [])
          }
          this.$set(file, 'votes', data.data().votes)
          if (this.$set(file, 'votes', data.data().votes)) {
            this.$set(file, 'votes', 0)
          }
          this.videoFiles.push(file) // await not necessary here as the push method does not return a promise and also is not asynchronous

          this.uploadDate = data.data().date
          console.log(this.videoFiles)
          this.videoFiles.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.date - b.date;
          })
        })
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
},
```

Like I said at the beginning, this first attempt isn't designed to make the logic work. There's a lot going on there that I don't understand. I have focused on removing redundant code and correcting syntax errors. I may be able to look at the logic if more detail is provided.